# Request in RestAssured

Tags: rest, rest-assured

What is the difference between request(Method) or .post(path)/.get(path) ?

Example:

- given().spec("url").basePath("path").body("body").when().request("POST")
- given().spec("url").body("body").when().post("path")

Comment: what is your actual problem? If you want to know these methods, just open its source code. That's it

Comment: voted to close since there is no feedback from OP for the entire day.